# Unexpected end of input error on cookie JSON parse

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I'm trying to parse a JSON string saved on a cookie back into a JSON object. Parsing the JSON string from the cookie reads an error while parsing the identical string that was not saved to the cookie works fine.

This code gives a "Unexpected end of input"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var keyStore={
"hello":"there"
}
document.cookie=JSON.stringify(keyStore);
var parsedData=JSON.parse(document.cookie);//Error is on this line!!!
console.log(parsedData);
});
```

While this code works fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var keyStore={
"hello":"there"
}
var stringifiedText=JSON.stringify(keyStore);
var parsedData=JSON.parse(stringifiedText);
console.log(parsedData);
});
```

Comment: when u run document.cookie can you see the stuff in it?

Comment: a quick console.log prints out, {"hello":"there"}